# Java - swing - Graphics2D - how to visualize math functions

Tags: java, math, charts, graphics2d, algebra

I've just faced an interesting thing as Math functions but as I can get it Math may contain float function values but Graphics2D can be used to paint just N values because pixels coordinates cannot be like 0.897 but 1 or 2 etc :(  So I just want to ask how to paint some simple math charts like in Java?

> y=x
>
> or
>
> y=x*tan(alpha)+3; abs(x)
>
> or
>
> y=x+5
>
> etc

I have found [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/MathFunctionChart.htm) kind of code; 
 [image]

OK it is quite interesting but it just paints chart with markers but otherwise how the function can be used to paint some other object each N pixels right upon it (not marker but to place a JLabel with markers coordinates for example)?  And how not to show the coordinates border ?

Comment: If you know how many decimal places would be the max, you could scale your function by that factor of 10 to make everything a whole number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811928/graphics2d-should-i-use-the-int-or-float-versions

Comment: @James Black Thanks for this link but I am interested in Math expressions but not in Rectangles, Lines etc. For example I tried to figure out how to follow all funtion(x) and draw a small circle each 10 pixels of it from x>=10 and x<=100 ? As follows, to paint right on a function(x) I need to get x,y coordinates for each circle center point and the coordinates must be Integer otherwise painting shouldn't be as smooth as it expected because I want to get a clear function line; I do hope there should be some standard way of it :)

Comment: ... but still I couldn't find any useful snippet in this direction :( Maybe I search wrong places?

Answer (score 0):

The return values of some math functions can be scaled to the graph's viewing window.  Since you're a math person, I'll put it in more math-like terms: you need to create a mapping function that can be applied to the output of your math function...so g(f(x)) where g translates a decimal return value to a pixel.

g(x) can be something as simple as: take the input and multiply it by y=100 supposing your viewing window is 100x100.  I hope this makes sense...you'll also want to consider which portion of the 2D graph you're viewing.  Are you viewing all 4 quadrants?  If so g(x) will need to translate the values too considering that the viewing window has changed...

I hope this makes sense!